Unital Banach algebra as a quotient of a free complex algebra
Let $\mathbb{C}\langle x_i:i\in I\rangle$ be the free complex noncommutative unital algebra over the generators $X:=\{ x_i:i\in I\}$. Then, every unital complex algebra $A$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{C}\langle x_i:i\in I\rangle$ over some ideal.

Question. If a norm turns $A$ into a Banach algebra, is it always possible to equip a norm on the free algebra $\mathbb{C}\langle x_i:i\in I\rangle$ so that it becomes a (not necessarily complete) normed algebra, and that the quotient map is continuous?

I'm trying to understand the transition from a purely algebraic ring/algebra theory to a topological one. I want to know whether we have to start from a Banach space and give it a continuous multiplication, or can we also start from an algebra and then give it a norm and completeness, without losing all the nice purely algebraic reasoning. Many of my previous questions were asked out of the same intention. Apologies if these seem weird to those specializing in Banach algebras and/or C*-algebras. Thanks in advance.
Example. Just to explain what I mean. Purely algebraically speaking, if $A\simeq FR(X)/I$, and $\pi$ is the canonical projection, then $\pi(\alpha)$ is invertible in $A$ iff the ideal $I$ contains $ab-1$ and $ba-1$ for some $b\in FR(X)$. But also, if $A$ is further a Banach algebra, then all the invertible elements form an open set. Lots of other results such as spectrum radius also can be established. But the way to prove them are mostly analytical and carry almost no trace of anything algebraic. I want to understand whether it's possible to eliminate such a schism. Hope that makes sense.

please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265443/what-algebras-are-quotients-of-ell-1-mathbfn

A standard construction used a lot in the $C^\ast$-algebra theory is equipping a purely algebraic construction with some kind of universal norm, which applies here. I’ll assume all $x_i$ are understood to represent contractions - in particular, the quotient maps we’re considering send any $x_i$ to an element of norm at most $1$. Then we may equip $FR(X) = \mathbb{C}\langle x_i: i \in I\rangle$ with the norm:
$$\|x\| = \sup_{\pi: FR(X) \to A} \|\pi(x)\|$$
Where $\pi$ ranges over all algebraic homomorphism $FR(X) \to A$ where $A$ is a normed algebra and $\|\pi(x_i)\| \leq 1$ for all $i$. I’ll leave it to you to check that this is indeed a well-defined norm, and it makes $FR(X)$ into a normed algebra with the property that whenever $\pi: FR(X) \to B$ is an algebraic homomorphism that sends all $x_i$ to contractions, then $\pi$ is automatically bounded (in fact even contractive).
Now, in this specific case, this universal norm is in fact just the $\ell^1$-norm, on the basis consisting of monomials in $x_i$. But this construction can be applied in many more cases. For example, the universal tensor norm for the tensor product of two $C^\ast$-algebras, or the universal norm on the group ring of a group that leads to the full group $C^\ast$-algebra, etc.

May I ask, in the definition of the norm, is $A$ a given fixed algebra, as in my question, or is it arbitrary? That is, are both $\pi$ and $A$ changing, or only $\pi$ changes? Thanks

@user760 $A$ is arbitrary.

Apology for commenting so late, but how can $\pi$ change at all? If $A$ is generated by $X:={x_i:i\in I}$, doesn't that mean $\pi: FR(X)\to A$ is fixed? If $A$ also changes, wouldn't that mean the generating set $X$ is also changing, and $FR(X)$ is not even fixed?
